# Insert data to postgres table

Tags: postgresql, insert, timestamp

I'm Trying to insert the data from csv file which was exported from Oracle DB. when I try to import on PGadmin. its failing with below error.

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "29-APR-18
>   12.04.07.000000000 AM" CONTEXT:  COPY consolidated_dtls_job_log, line 1, column start_time: "29-APR-18 12.04.07.000000000 AM"

*Note: Column **Start_time** is created with timestamp datatype.*

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: That doesn’t look like anything PostgreSQL by default would accept as a valid timestamp format. Might need to convert the data into something more standard first, or import as text and then convert in PostgreSQL afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` when exporting the data from Oracle; something that is closer to the ISO format.

Here is an SQL statement provided by Belayer:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM';
```

Comment: In Oracle execute "alter session set NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT  = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM'; Then re-export your data.

Comment: Thanks; I shamelessly incorporated that statement into my answer.